# Create model and fill it according to API response JSON

Tags: java, model-view-controller, groovy

I am trying to make a model, json model. When I get the response I should parse them and fill my model. I really don’t get it how it should be done. For example for response I receive:

```
"userId": 1,
"userAccess": 1,
"CE": "WP",
```

and I should make model like that and that model should be filled according to that response.
My model should look like that I think:

```
"userId": ,
"userAccess": ,
"CE": "",
```

and my model must be filled according to response, like
userId must be filled with 1, userAcces with 1 and CE with "WP"

I have no problem with parsing a json from API response, but I have no idea how then my model should be filled with that parsed json.

This is how I am trying to parse my json:

```
public MyApiService(Integer someId) {
        String endpoint = "http://test-coregatewayapi.com/os/" + someId
        RequestObject request  =  findTestObject('Object Repository/Loans_Requests/ColGet/GET')
        request.setRestUrl(endpoint)
        ResponseObject resp = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(request)
        String getcontent = resp.getResponseBodyContent()
        parsedJson = slurper.parseText(getcontent)
    }

    public int getData() {
        return parsedJson[0]['dataId']
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried?  E.g. Jackson allows binding data to objects.

Comment: I have updated my question with the attached code.

Comment: The output you are looking for is a flag in `ToString(includeNames=true)` - see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/ToString.html and IMHO this is not part of the original question (you asked for the mapping and not how to pretty print it)

Comment: I have already answered my question with the code, well yes printing the result was not the main question. I've figured it out how to make a model and fill it with received json data.

Comment: If you found a solution for your problem, you should add an answer instead of changing your question into another one.  For your next problem then create a new question.

Comment: Well, I have added answer below, also what have I added answers my original question. I don't have answered how it should be printed.

Comment: This is what i was suggesting: remove the answer from your question.  also remove the question about toString.  next create a new question about your toString problem.  SO is about Question and Answer.  So keep your Q simple for one specific problem.

Comment: Okay, I did so as you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out how to resolve my question.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyApiService {

JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()

    public MyApiService() {

    }

    public JsonModel MyApiServiceCall(Integer someId) {
        String endpoint = "http://test-coregatewayapi.com/v1/" + someId
        RequestObject request  =  findTestObject('Object Repository/Deposits_Requests/GET/GET_De')
        request.setRestUrl(endpoint)
        ResponseObject resp = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(request)
        String getcontent = resp.getResponseBodyContent()
        def parsedJson = slurper.parseText(getcontent)
        def newModel = new JsonModel(parsedJson)
        return newModel
    }


}

@ToString
    class JsonModel {
        String typeId
        boolean isOk
        Float balance
    }
```

and in the main test case I just simply use this:

```
MyApiService test = new MyApiService()
JsonModel model=test.MyApiServiceCall(39)

def k = model.type
```

Where I can get any of my parsed objects.

Comment: Note that using the Map c'tor will throw if the map contains keys, the object has no property for.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it.

Comment: If the map (newModel) you are passing into the implicit Map constructor of JsonModel contain any other keys than typeId, isOk, ballance, this will throw an MissingPropertyException

Answer (score 2):

It depends on framework you are using.

For example with gson:

```
String json = "{\"brand\":\"Jeep\", \"doors\": 3}"
Gson gson = new Gson()
Car car = gson.fromJson(json, Car.class)
```

In plain groovy

```
 def json = new JsonSlurper().parse(...) as Car
```

Comment: I use JsonSlurper, I have updated my question with the code what I am using.

Comment: Please note that a cast only works if the map doesn't contain keys beyond the fields of your target class.  While this fails silently (**no** field is set) you get at least an exception if using the map c'tor.

Comment: @daggett Can we talk in the room ?